# Ion Auth cant login after install

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication, ion-auth

I have installed ion auth, my server dont support bcrypt so made it sha1, now i cant login using default password. gives me login incorrect, i have also tried changing password in database using sha1 function but no avail.

Please help.

here is config :

```
$config['hash_method']    = 'sha1'; // sha1 or bcrypt, bcrypt is STRONGLY recommended
$config['default_rounds'] = 8;      // This does not apply if random_rounds is set to true
$config['random_rounds']  = FALSE;
$config['min_rounds']     = 5;
$config['max_rounds']     = 9;
$config['salt_prefix']    = '$2a$';
```

here is db user password :5baa61e4c9b93f3f0682250b6cf8331b7ee68fd8

Answer (score 1):

In the comments in the config/ion_auth.php file there is the password hash you should update your database with if you switch to SHA1.  As long as you're using the default password.

Comment: i did that , it did'nt work, i reinstalled in seperate application and it worked.